# ThinkingSphinx::Search collection mix with some fresh ActiveRecord data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

We use number of servers with Sphinx as a separated layer to provide the searching. **Indexer** runs by cron independently to reduce data flow and searching indexing coupling.

With according to requirements we should provide real-time searching (without any delays), so we decided to keep Sphinx result that reindexes every 40 minutes and mix with fresh actual data from ActiveRecord model based on **updated_at** column, actually not older than 40min. It means we have actual data without using of delta functionality (which adds some kind of coupling).

The questions is how we can merge ThinkingSphinx::Search result and ActiveRecord data to do ordering and paginate through whole data set. Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [real-time indexes](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#rt-indexes).

Comment: does real-time indexes work with ThinkingSphinx already? Dmitriy, seems you have no experience with it, just see https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/issues/186

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't pay attention to the fact that you're using ThinkingSphinx.But using of RT indexes is the best solution for your task and it's very sad that this functionality is not implemented in ThinkingSphinx. Maybe you should use some delta index and rotate it every time new record is appear? I just don't see the point of trying to combine those things you want.

Comment: I'm working on RT indices - it's not a simple matter to switch things over though. In the meantime, you should probably look at TS's support for delta indexing: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/deltas.html